# addtional income in visa form

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I work in a restaurant and I get weekly tips/gratuities which varies from $150-$200. Can anyone let me know that I should mention that in my visa form as I don’t want them to think its unreasonable money. Any suggestion guys?

Comment: Can you demonstrate sufficient funds for the trip without your gratuities? Any income you state in the application should be backed up by evidence that it was legally obtained eg pay slips, tax returns plus your bank statements https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: Yes, i earn $3000 monthly excluding gratuities and my bank statement have 6500-7000 for visa and my trip cost is hardly $2500 as i am visiting family so mostly ticket expense and shopping. Thank you for taking time and answering